# Как убрать класс active если мы находимся на другом стейте?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Использую $stateProvider вот код:

```
.state('books', {
  url: '/main',
  controller: 'MainCtrl'})
.state('books.home', {
  url: '/home',
  controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
.state('books.about', {
  url: '/about',
  controller: 'AboutCtrl'})
```

Написал директиву в которой вот такой код:

```
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="books">main</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="books.home">home</a></li>
<li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="books.about">about</a></li>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что у ui-sref="books" всегда присвоен класс active, даже если я перехожу на home или about. Как сделать так чтоб этот класс не присваивался родительскому стейту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В описании к директиве [ui-sref-active](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active) говорится

> Will activate when the ui-sref's **target** state or **any child** state is  active.  If you need to activate only when the ui-sref target state is active and not any of it's children, then you will use [ui-sref-active-eq](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active-eq)

То есть, класс будет присваиваться, если текущий state совпадает с указанным в ui-sref, или если выбран любой дочерний state. Если нужно точное соответствие, то нужно использовать директиву `ui-sref-active-eq`

Пример:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])

.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('books', {
      url: '/main',
      controller: function() {}
    })
    .state('books.home', {
      url: '/home',
      controller: function() {}
    })
    .state('books.about', {
      url: '/about',
      controller: function() {}
    })
})
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="ui-router@0.2.13" data-semver="0.2.13" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.13/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>
  <ul>
    <li ui-sref-active-eq="active"><a ui-sref="books">main</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active-eq="active"><a ui-sref="books.home">home</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active-eq="active"><a ui-sref="books.about">about</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```